# Reading error object in react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, action

I am making an AJAX call, when it is successful I can read the response as returned by the API, but when there is an error, I only get the error from the server, but not the message

This is my Action code

```
export const updateUsersAction = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(beginRequest());
    return updateUsers(id)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(updateUsersSuccess());
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(defaultError(error));
        throw (error);
      });
  };
};
```

The error from the server when id is not found is #400, but there is a specific message

```
{
    "error_message": "The id for this team was not found"    
}
```

How do I read that error_message? Thank you

```
export const updateUsers = function(id) {

  return axios.post(
    `/api/update_users/`,
    {
      id: id
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: did you tried to `console.log(error)` to have a look at the insights of the returning error object?

Comment: @rieckpil yes, I get "Error: Request failed with status code 404  at createError at settle at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad"

Comment: so when logging the `error` object you get the plain "Error: ..." to your console? You don't see a JSON object structure? The nested message is sometimes in `error.data` . Can you post the related server side code?

Comment: @rieckpil no there is no json, that is all I am getting. I'll update the question with the ajax call

Comment: do you have access to the backend code for this api code?

Comment: @rieckpil no, I don't. I think i can maybe find a solution here https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: @rieckpil I found it, it is in error.response.data, thanks!

Comment: Always remember to use a debugger on your dev tools in your source file. It always shows you an object of the Error on debugger if you hover on the error obj, then you could have find it properly that it's error.response.data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error JSON can be found on error.response.data, in this case error.response.data.error_message

Reference https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors